# Resetting CSS with Javascript & fixing "bug" in buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here](https://codepen.io/alicia_van_zijl/pen/YdRKZx) is my code on Codepen.

```js
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "400px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}


//Option: Red Luigi
document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("click", makeRed);

function makeRed(){
  //activate animation & color
  document.getElementById("drink").classList.add("animate");
  document.getElementById("drink").classList.add("run-red");
  //display garnish image
  document.getElementById("garnish").src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2365343/lemon%20slice.png";
  //write recipe in sidenav
  document.getElementById("recipe-name").innerHTML = "Luigi";
  //write recipe instructions
  document.getElementById("method").innerHTML = "Fill up the mixer glass with ice cubes. Pour grenadine, orange juice, Cointreau, dry vermouth, and gin into the mixer glass. Stir together. Strain into the cocktail glass. Garnish.";
  //write list
  var contents, text, fLen, i;
contents = ["2 parts gin", "1/2 part dry vermouth", "1 dash Cointreau", "1/2 part grenadine", "1/2 part orange juice", "ice cubes"];
fLen = contents.length;

text = "<ul>";
  
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + contents[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML = text;
}

//Option: Yellow
document.getElementById("yellow").addEventListener("click", makeYellow);

function makeYellow(){
  //activate animation & color
  document.getElementById("drink").classList.add("animate");
  document.getElementById("drink").classList.add("run-yellow");
  //display garnish image
  document.getElementById("garnish").src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2365343/umbrella.png";
  //write recipe in sidenav
  document.getElementById("recipe-name").innerHTML = "Scotch & Schnapps Sweetheart";
  //write recipe instructions
  document.getElementById("method").innerHTML = "Add ice to the shaker. Add peach schnapps, milk, mango, egg white, and Scotch to the shaker. Shake well. Strain into the cocktail glass.";
  //write list
  var contents, text, fLen, i;
contents = ["2 parts Scotch", "2 parts peach schnapps", "1 part passion fruit juice", "1/2 part milk", "ice"];
fLen = contents.length;

text = "<ul>";
  
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + contents[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML = text;
}

//Option: Green
document.getElementById("green").addEventListener("click", makeGreen);

function makeGreen(){
  //activate animation & color
  document.getElementById("drink").classList.add("animate");
  document.getElementById("drink").classList.add("run-green");
  //display garnish image
  document.getElementById("garnish").src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2365343/mint_2.png";
    //write recipe in sidenav
  document.getElementById("recipe-name").innerHTML = "Mintini";
  //write recipe instructions
  document.getElementById("method").innerHTML = "Fill up the shaker with ice. Pour peppermint schnapps, mint liqueur, and vodka into the shaker. Shake well. Strain into the cocktail glass. Garnish with candy cane or mint.";
  //write list
  var contents, text, fLen, i;
contents = ["2 parts vodka", "1 part mint schnapps", "1 part mint liqueur", "ice cubes"];
fLen = contents.length;

text = "<ul>";
  
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + contents[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML = text;
}


//Resetting the animation
"use strict";

var element = document.getElementById("drink");

element.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  
  element.classList.remove("animate", "run-red", "run-yellow", "run-green");
  document.getElementById("garnish").src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2365343/placeholder.png";
  document.getElementById("recipe-name").innerHTML = "Choose a drink to see the recipe."
  document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("method").innerHTML = ""
  
  void element.offsetWidth;
  
  element.classList.add("");
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  background: #002A32;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2365343/webpage%20hero%20banner.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* The recipe menu */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 3; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #EE786E;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The recipe text */
.sidenav h1 {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #271F30;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav p {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.sidenav ul {
  text-align: left;
  list-style: inside;
}

.sidenav li {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}




/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #FCEEB5;
}


.title h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.title h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.choice {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/* buttons */

.button {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center; 
}

#red {
  background-color: #EE786E;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: #FCEEB5;
}

#green {
  background-color: #A2CCB6;
}

#recipe-btn {
  background-color: #271F30;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

/* Glass */
.glass {
  border-left: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  border-top: 200px solid #87a9c4;
  opacity: .6;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: -90px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* stem */
.glass:before {
  height: 121px;
  width: 4px;
  background: #87a9c4;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 60%;
  position: relative;
}

/* base */
.glass:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #87a9c4;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  top: 120px;
  position: absolute;
}

#garnish {
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 100px;
}


/* contents */
span {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 44px;
  margin-left: -78px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-left: 108px solid transparent;
  border-right: 108px solid transparent;
  border-top: 180px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: fillGlass 3s forwards;
  animation: fillGlass 3s forwards;
}


.run-red {
  border-top: 180px solid #EE786E;
}

.run-yellow {
  border-top: 180px solid #FCEEB5;
}

.run-green {
  border-top: 180px solid #A2CCB6;
}



@-webkit-keyframes fillGlass {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.25, .25);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.5, .5);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    }
  100% {
    transform: scale(.8, .8);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
  }
}
@keyframes fillGlass {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.25, .25);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.5, .5);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    }
  100% {
    transform: scale(.8, .8);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <h1 id="recipe-name">Choose a drink to see the recipe.</h1>
  <div id="ingredients"><ul></ul></div>
  <p id="method"></p>
</div>


  
<div id="main">
  
  <div class="title"><h1>Peachy Cocktails</h1><h2>Choose your cocktail. Click on the glass to drink it and have another!</h2></div>
  
    <div class="choice">
  <button class="button" id="green">Mintini</button>
  <button class="button" id="yellow">Scotch & Schnapps Sweetheart</button>
  <button class="button" id="red">Luigi</button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
<button id="recipe-btn" class="button" onclick="openNav()">Show Recipe</button>
  
<div class="center">
  <div class="glass"></div>
  <span id="drink" class=""></span>
  <img id="garnish" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2365343/placeholder.png">
  
    </div>

  </div>
  
</body>
```

I completed this little page as a training challenge - It features a simple CSS drawing of a cocktail glass which "fills" with three different colors ("drinks") on button clicks.  I'm aware that the graphic is far from perfect. However, I'm trying to achieve a couple of things:

1) Users can switch between drink options by clicking a button. This should start the animation and change the color. It also changes the recipe displayed in the collapsible side panel.

2) The animation should reset so that the fill is animated every time.

I ended up doing this by putting a reset button into the graphic - by clicking the glass, it "empties" and the animation is reset.

I have two problems:

1) It is possible to change the drink without resetting the animation by clicking the buttons in the order of the CSS styling.  I'd rather that the animation resets automatically before loading the new animation.

2) The Javascript code looks messy and bloated.  I have a lot of repetition and I'd there is a cleaner way to code this.  Is it possible to include the "reset" into the buttons rather than using a separate reset button?

All feedback and fixes would be gratefully received.

Comment: This would be better posted in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @Adam I'll give that a try too.

Comment: Hi @Adam I've double-checked and this question is not suitable for CodeReview because: "Code Review is for open-ended questions about code that already works correctly (to the best of your knowledge). Questions seeking help about debugging or understanding code are off-topic for Code Review, and may be on-topic for Stack Overflow." My code is not working 100% correctly and has a specific issue.  Once I've fixed that I'll try Code Review.